# Change the redirect_uri when first running npm run dev

Tags: node.js, npm, shopify, shopify-api, npm-run

I am trying to run the shopify app on Digital Ocean. When I run `npm run dev` for the very first time I need to login to Shopify Partners via the generated link. But the link has the parameter `&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3456&s` so a localhost. So after logging into Shopify Parnters I get redirected to localhost to finish the process but I cannot access it since its on Digital Ocean. Can I change that parameter somehow?

I tried the `--hostname`, `--redirect_uri`, `--tunnel-url` flags. Looked up the documentation here: https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/cli/commands#dev but couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You set your tunnel (where your App runs on your local machine) in the App setup as an important step. So that is likely to be something.ngrok.io or perhaps you choose Cloudflare. Either way, that is an address Shopify will use. Now in your package.json file, alter the command to use that. As an example, I use ngrok, so one of my apps has the command:

```
 "dev": "shopify app dev --tunnel-url=https://baboon.ngrok.io:3147",
```

So now when I run my yarn dev command, Shopify uses the correct tunnel and port. There are other small things to do, but you'll figure it out once you get to this point.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I didnt work, I still get redirected to 127.0.0.1:3456 after logging in to Shopify Partners. This is the output:<br/>
npm run dev<br/>
> appname@1.0.0 dev<br/>
> shopify app dev --tunnel-url=http://8.8.8.8:3147<br/>
<br/>

To run this command, log in to Shopify Partners.<br/>
 Press any key to open the login page on your browser<br/>
Auto-open timed out. Open the login page: Log in to Shopify Partners (​http://accounts.shopify.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=...)